# Баг с вкладкой конкурсные вопросы

Tags: дефект

Заходя по метке php мы видем что нет конкурсных вопросов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она скрыта. Но если на главной странице выбрать конкурсные вопросы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в тегах перейти на php тег то мы видим что конкурсная вкладка выбранна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидаемый результаты:

```
 1. При переходе на php тэг перенаправлять на вкладку "новые" если
вкладка "конкурсные" пуста и скрыта для видимости.
 2. Не скрывать вкладку если там 0
```

Answer (score 1):

*(ответ написан к [старой ревизии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3727/1), когда в вопросе ожидалось перенаправление на другую вкладку с вопросами вместо попадания на пустой список конкурсных вопросов)*

---

### Нет, пожалуйста, не надо.

#### "Когда запрашивается одно, почему выводится совсем другое?"

Если я добавлю ссылку на конкурсную страницу в закладки (и тем самым перестану зависеть от наличия или отсутствия ссылки на страницах сайта) и буду периодически туда посматривать, перенаправление на "новые вопросы" мне будет только мешать, показывая вместо конкурсных вопросов неконкурсные.

Я, правда, так не делаю. Но предложение, на мой взгляд, *ломает* вполне логичный UX.

Comment: причём тут закладка вы просто открываете вкладку конкурсные на главной странице, потом переходите в тэги жмёте php в данном случае, в котором вкладка конкурсные скрыта(так как там нет айтимов) и вы попадаете на вкладку конкурсные она уже отображаеться как активная но она была скрыта до этого.

Comment: т.е. тут можно предложить просто не скрывать данную вкладку если там 0

Comment: @Naumov вариант "не скрывать вовсе" мне уже больше нравится. Но то, что предложено в вопросе, я не одобряю.

Comment: @Naumov добавил в ответ пояснение того, при чём тут закладки.

Comment: Поправил ожидаемый вариантты